# Having trouble in part 2.3.5 of railstutorial.org, getting a 404 error on the deployment page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

Having trouble in part 2.3.5 of railstutorial.org, getting a 404 error on the deployment page. Any ideas why? Heroku log looks clean

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
>
> You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

LOGS BELOW, thanks for your help:

> 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872271+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in
>   `tagged' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872271+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`
>   tagged' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872271+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872444+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872444+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872444+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872444+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872444+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872444+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872444+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872444+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872444+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
>   2013-12-14T00:18:49.872444+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872598+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in`
>   service' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872598+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-12-14T00:18:49.872598+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in
>   `service' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872598+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
>   2013-12-14T00:18:49.872598+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
>   start_thread' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872598+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
>   2013-12-14T00:18:49.872598+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-12-14T00:18:49.872598+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-12-14T00:18:49.872598+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.872598+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873063+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873063+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873063+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873063+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873063+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`
>   call_app' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873063+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873236+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873236+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873236+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873236+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873236+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
>   2013-12-14T00:18:49.873236+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873236+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in`
>   service' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873236+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in
>   `service' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873236+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
>   2013-12-14T00:18:49.873063+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in
>   `block in call' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873063+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`
>   block in tagged' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873063+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in
>   `tagged' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873063+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`
>   tagged' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873236+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
>   start_thread' 2013-12-14T00:18:49.873570+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-12-14T00:18:49.873570+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-12-14T00:18:50.183847+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path=/favicon.ico host=pure-basin-6606.herokuapp.com
>   fwd="50.177.117.96" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304
>   bytes=0 2013-12-14T00:18:49.877507+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info
>   method=GET path=/ host=pure-basin-6606.herokuapp.com
>   fwd="50.177.117.96" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=15ms status=404
>   bytes=1351 2013-12-14T00:33:02.653417+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET
>   "/" for 50.177.117.96 at 2013-12-14 00:33:02 +0000
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.654408+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.653417+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/"
>   for 50.177.117.96 at 2013-12-14 00:33:02 +0000
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.654408+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654408+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`
>   call_app' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654408+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in
>   `block in call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654408+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.654408+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.654408+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`
>   block in tagged' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654408+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in
>   `tagged' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654408+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`
>   tagged' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654408+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654575+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654575+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654575+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654575+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654575+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654575+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654575+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654575+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654575+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.654736+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in
>   `service' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654736+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`
>   service' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654736+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.654575+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654736+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
>   start_thread' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654736+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.654736+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655209+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in
>   `call_app' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654736+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.654736+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.654736+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.654736+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.655209+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in
>   `block in call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655209+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`
>   block in tagged' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655209+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in
>   `tagged' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655209+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655209+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in
>   `tagged' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655209+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655209+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655209+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655209+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655367+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655367+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655367+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655367+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in
>   `call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655367+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in`
>   call' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655367+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.655367+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`
>   service' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655367+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in
>   `service' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655367+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.655367+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in
>   start_thread' 2013-12-14T00:33:02.655706+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2013-12-14T00:33:02.655706+00:00 app[web.1]:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial, Michael says:

> Unfortunately, the resulting page is an error; as of Rails 4.0, for technical reasons the default Rails page doesn’t work on Heroku. The good news is that the error will go away (in the context of the full sample application) when we add a root route in Section 5.3.2. 
>   - [1.4.3 Heroku deployment, step two](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec-1_4_3)

You might haven't created the top page yet in section 2.3.5. If it's your case, setting proper route to existing page would do.

Also you can refer to Heroku dev center :

> Rails 4 no longer has a static index page in production. When you’re using a new app, there will not be a root page in production, so we need to create one. We will first create a controller called welcome for our home page to live: - [Getting Started with Rails 4.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4)

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  I will just have to push forward with the tutorial at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 no longer has a static index page in production. When we're using a new app, there will not be a root page in production, so we need to create one. We need to create a controller called welcome for our home page:

```
$ rails generate controller welcome
```

Next we may want to add an index page (app/views/welcome/index.html.erb) write:

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>
<p>
  The time is now: <%= Time.now %>
</p>
```

Now we need to have Rails route to this action. We'll edit config/routes.rb to set the index page to our new method (actually, we need to uncomment the line):

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

Comment: To simply access the demo_app (without bothering to create a root page as above), add /users to your app's Heroku root URL, like this: http://fathomless-taiga-5681.herokuapp.com/users